# Django 2.0 - test using fixtures from dumpdata gives utf8mb4 encoding errors

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, utf8mb4, fixture

I am using utf8mb4 encoding for my mySQL database.
All my Django apps work correctly with it even with Cyrillic characters.

But when I run `./manage.py test <module>` and try to load a fixture dumped from the same database, I get errors regarding the encoding. One of the errors is:

`Could not load advert.Region(pk=1): (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD0\\x9F\\xD0\\xBB\\xD0\\xBE...' for column 'region_name' at row 1")`

Then I set DEFAULT_CHARSET in the Django settings and the error changed to
`LookupError: Problem installing fixture '<path>/test_db_one.xml': unknown encoding: utf8mb4`

As you can see I have specified the format of the fixture to be XML as it has better handling of the encoding.

My setting module has the following properties:

```
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf8mb4'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'autoplusplus_dev',
        'USER': 'autoplusplus_django',
        'PASSWORD': '1029',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'INNODB',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
        'TEST_CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
    }
}
```

I have mysqlclient 1.3.12 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that changing the encoding of the file which Django generates itself to UTF-8 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `Пло`?  If so, that is reasonable UTF-8 encoding.

"unknown encoding: utf8mb4" -- You have an antique version of Django and/or MySQL?  What versions are you running?

What does the table definition look like?  Maybe the columns are `latin1` instead of `utf8` or `utf8mb4`.

Meanwhile, use MySQL's `CHARACTER SET utf8`; this *may* get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turned out I had to change the encoding of the xml file itself and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Hmmm...  I thought XML had to be UTF-8.